# Django-React deployed app how to go to admin app

Tags: reactjs, django, heroku

I have a web app running on `Django API` on the backend and `React` on the frontend, after deploying it to `Heroku` everything is working great except I don't know how to go to the admin page since I used to access it locally (before deployment) it via 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ while the main page was running on localhost:3000/

Comment: the admin page related to your Reactjs project or Django project?

Comment: the Django admin page

Comment: What's your Django back-end Heroku URL ?

Comment: when i deployed i had everything in the same folder backend and frontend so now i have the mainpage in `https://hope-xun.herokuapp.com/` and The Django API is in `https://hope-xun.herokuapp.com/API/`

Comment: Just tried the URL : https://hope-xun.herokuapp.com/admin/

Answer (score 2):

Turns out i needed to add a backslash at the end `https://hope-xun.herokuapp.com/admin/`